# Magento memory allocation

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am running a script on my magento store. Its suppose to create an XML file with my products but when I hit this php file, I get the following error.

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 55574528) (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/sparklin/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 290

I am thinking I should increase memory allocation on my server. But I don't know how to that. any help?

Comment: What version of Magento, there is a memory leak in older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing memory in php.ini and restart apache and see if that works.

`memory_limit = 16M` to your php.ini file (recommended, if you have access)

or refer here:

[Or you can find more details here...](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/allowed_memory_size_exhausted)

Cheers

Comment: OK I know this was 4 years ago, but I just had to mention, 16M is not going to be enough by a very long shot. According to the error message shown, the OP had 53M (why 53? Search me).
The current recommendation for Magento seems to be 512MB.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced a similar problem on Magento 1.7.0.2.

No matter how high I set my PHP `memory_limit`, I would continue to get:

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxx bytes) in xxx.php`

In my case the problem was not anything to do with memory.

A custom model I'd developed was at fault:

```
    class Package_Module_Model_Modelname extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

        public function _construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->_init('module/model');
        }
    ...
    }
```

By changing the  `parent::__construct()` to simply `parent::_construct()`  (single underscore) solved the problem!

Calling the native constructor of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` was the problem.

Comment: how to check to find which extensions causing problem?  i am getting same error now. out of memory Out of memory (allocated 693895168) (tried to allocate 32 bytes) Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 290   what should i do ?  it was working fine.

Comment: Try disabling all the extensions that might be responsible (everything except the Mage_* ones if need be) and see if the problem goes away. If it does, re-enable them one by one until the problem reappears. (To disable a module, change <active>true</active> to <active>false</active> in the relevant XML file in app/etc/modules.)

Answer (score 0):

When I made sure the cronjob was able to run -> the error disappears.
Greets